# searching an element tree using dfs

Tags: python, xml, parsing, search, depth-first-search

My program is supposed to use a DFS function to search an XML tree and print out the childs of that event that was entered. The issue i'm having so far is trying to parse the element tree into a format that my dfs function will take.

My Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='XMLStuff3.xml')


root = tree.getroot()









def dfs(adjLists, s):
    stack = [s]
    visited = set()

    while stack:
        v = stack.pop()
        if v in visited:
            continue
        print(v, " ", end='')

        visited.add(v)
        yield v
        for w in adjLists.get(v, []):
            stack.append(w)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------



from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('XMLStuff3.xml') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for node in tree.iter():

    print(node.attrib)



l1 =[]
while True:
    event = input("Enter Event (or Enter to quit): ")
    if not event:
        break
    for child in  root:
        l1 = [ child.attrib['action'] for child in root ]
        if any(event in e for e in l1):
            dfs(node.attrib, event) #Event is supposed to go into dfs as the root node where the function returns the childs of that node


            print("Match", )

        else:
            print('No Match')


print("Done")
```

XML file i'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <node action="Stay" response="">
        <node action="" response="Pause Menu"/>
        <node action="" response="Sit"/>
    </node>
    <node action="Enemy Rushing User" response="">
        <node action="" response="Dodge Left"/>
        <node action="" response="Dodge Right"/>
    </node>
    <node action="Move" response="">
        <node action="Reverse" response="">
            <node action="" response="Back Left"/>
            <node action="" response="Back Straight"/>
            <node action="" response="Back Middle"/>
        </node>
        <node action="Forward" response="">
            <node action="" response="Forward Left"/>
            <node action="" response="Forward Straight"/>
            <node action="" response="Forward Right"/>
        </node>
    </node>
</root>
```

So far when I enter an event like 'Stay' it will find a match, but the dfs function on the next line down doesn't execute because it's not in the right format. The format that the function will take that I've tried and works by itself is:

```
adjLists1 = {'0':['One','Two','Three'], '1':['Four'], '2':['Five','Six'], '3':['Seven','Eight'], '4':[],
             '5':['Nine','Ten','Eleven'], '6':['Twelve','Thirteen','Fourteen'], '7':[], '8':[]
```

My general question would be how would I parse my xml tree into that format? I've tried just using 'node.attrib' as the 'adjLists' parameter in the dfs function and it's close to that format but not enough.

Comment: How is the expected output related to the input? I see no connection between the two.

Comment: For example, when I type in an event like 'Stay' first it looks for a match in the table. Once there's a match then i call the dfs function where the first parameter input is the xml table or node.attrib. What is supposed to happen is the event 'Stay' would be the root node and second parameter input in the dfs function and what would print out would be all the child nodes of 'Stay'. But what I'm trying to do and having issue with is finding a way to parse the node.attrib so that the dfs function I call executes. the adjLists1 It's just a example of what the dfs takes and is not related.